# Android Kotlin Webview in Background?

Tags: android, kotlin

My application is basically a webview. The page it opens runs on web-sockets.

However, when I lock my phone, the web-socket connection gets broken... since the application is no longer in focus. How can I keep this webview and it's web-sockets running in the background so that the connection isn't lost when the phone goes to sleep?

```
    webWindow = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    webWindow.loadUrl("http://8wr.io/scoreboard/")
    webWindow.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webWindow.settings.userAgentString = "com.ewr.scoreboardassistant"
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have this in an `Activity` or in a `Service`.  If it is in an `Activity` class, when your phone goes to sleep, the activity is stopped, which could halt the web-socket connection.

If you really want to keep a process running even when your phone goes to sleep, it has to be served as a `Service`. Even services get destroyed though, but when you think of a music streaming app, they are kept alive.

Please have a look at this link: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

In short, if you want to keep running something even when the phone goes to sleep, it must be implemented as a foreground service.

Comment: Is there an easy way to convert my Activity to a Service?

Comment: you have to make separate service for web socket connection and start this service inside of activity